# Salary 'in hand' or 'on hand'?

Tags: prepositions

Quite confusing for me as I have read/heard both.

> Your salary in/on hand will be X amount.

What it takes and why? To me, both seem correct.

Comment: I'm guessing that "salary in/on hand" is probably InE. I've heard only "salary", "gross salary", and "net salary". I tried to think of "salary on hand" the same way I think of "cash on hand", but it doesn't seem to work well. So I searched the web and found that "net salary" = "salary in hand" in this discussion:  that "net salary" = "salary in hand".

Comment: It looks like InE speakers prefer *in*, but I can find examples of both.  In AmE we don't generally use this expression to refer to take-home pay, at least in my experience.

Comment: @DamkerngT. I see. I never thought of that. Here, it's as common as *'How are you!'*. But wait, I read it on non-Indian sites as well. Anyway, I'm not sure but in this case, what you think is grammatically more preferable?

Comment: @snailplane it's in many books by native speakers as well (In fact, I found it in **Minutes of the Michigan Annual Conference**). So, let's think about it. But in any case, what you think is grammatically preferable?

Comment: @MaulikV I pasted the link incorrectly. Here is the link of that discussion: http://www.citehr.com/43685-how-find-hand-salary-ctc.html. I think "in hand" seems to be preferred, but I couldn't say anything for sure.

Comment: @DamkerngT. You find both used in equal frequency. But grammatically, you think *in-hand* is okay. Fine. Any reason? Isn't *in-hand* would mean that you have a currency note in your fist? We often tell kids - *don't hide, show me, what's **in your hand**?* Don't you think *on hand* is more preferable - something like this - http://www.torange.us/photo/2/13/A-pile-of-dollars-on-hand-1240581060_49.jpg

Comment: @MaulikV (EDIT) "Cash on hand" means something rather specific (similar to "petty cash", and your photo reminds me of it.) I couldn't find both of "salary in/on hand" really used as a set phrase in books on Google Books. Based on the books there, I'd still say "salary in hand" is preferred.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Yeah...I'm learning here. Thanks for all this discussion.

Answer (score 2):

This expression seems to be an Indian English holdover of what is now a somewhat archaic British English expression.

To have something **in hand** means that it is in your immediate possession. This is now somewhat archaic in American English and survives mostly in a few specific contexts:

> He stood, **gun in hand,** and listened for the screams he knew would come.
>
> The two of them walked down the pier **hand in hand.**
>
> Three goals up with four minutes remaining, the red team had the game **well in hand.**

This seems to be the sense you say it's used in in India--at the end of the day, this is how much money you'll actually be given, once everything has been deducted. I don't think this is the sense a native UK or American English speaker who was not familiar with the Indian expression would give it, but it is pretty close. Hearing the phrase with no context, I would expect it to refer to money given up front, excluding some specific money to be paid at a later date: "I'll pay you five hundred in hand, and five hundred when the job is done." But it's not a common idiom here for any meaning.

To be **on hand** means that you have something in your possession, but it is usually used in a more continuous context. It would seem odd to me to use "on hand" to describe a transaction. Usually it gives more of a sense of an existing supply:

> We have fifty barrels of oil on hand, but if you want to add churros to the menu, we'll need to increase our stockpile.
>
> Our cash on hand isn't enough to meet payroll. Get the gasoline can and meet me in the warehouse.
>
> Whenever I'm craving peanut butter, I never seem to have any on hand.

That being the case, it would make sense from an American and UK English perspective to say:

> Now that I've been paid, I have five hundred rupiya **on hand**.

or

> After taxes, my salary ended up being only five hundred rupiya **cash in hand.**

Answer (score 0):

You should think more about the difference between on and in as prepositions:
**On** is used to express activity on a surface of something, while **In** indicate a location or place.

In conclusion in hand seems more appropriate to me because it indicates that the money are put in your hand.

Comment: your sentence is contradictory to your own example. Can't someone put bills **on** someone's hand? http://www.torange.us/photo/2/13/A-pile-of-dollars-on-hand-1240581060_49.jpg Check the URL

Comment: That is what I am talking about- in hand means after the taxes, while on hand means with no documentation about the money. Hence **IN** hand is more relevant expression.

Answer (score 0):

> Your salary in hand will be $1000.

means you will get $1000 after paying taxes etc.

> Your salary on hand will be $1000.

would mean that out of your salary, you will have $1000 readily available to you: perhaps you will get another $500 in stock options, cheaper housing, etc - or perhaps you will only be allowed to access the rest of your salary when you become an adult (and until then it will accumulate in your bank account).

Note that the first one is significantly more used than the second one (which I haven't actually seen used in the meaning I explained above at all, but to me it's what the sentence actually means when you consider grammar etc).

Bottom line: chances are if you've seen someone write "salary on hand", it was probably a mistake, though it could technically also be used correctly (it just probably wasn't)...

Comment: What you mean the salary plus other things is CTC. Salary on/in hand is used what you have finally in your pocket without wages, cuttings or whatsoever.